# How to define the size of QT Opengl framebuffer

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

In GLFW we define the size of the Opengl framebuffer through this command.

```
 GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
```

This creates a opengl window of size 1920 X 1080 and the default frame buffer of Opengl is also of the same size.

How can we do the same in QT

This is how am i currently setting parameters for the opengl rendering.

```
QGLFormat  format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setSampleBuffers(true);
format.setSamples(4);
format.setSwapInterval(1);

QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

///////////////////////////////////// The GlWidget Class ////////////////

```
class GLWidget : public  QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
//  ~GLWidget();
    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
    QTimer timer;
    QElapsedTimer elapsedtimer;
    

private:
    int width;
    int height;

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void GLWidget::initializeGL() 
{
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)   // Check if glew is initialized properly
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Not able to Initialize Glew");
        msgBox.exec();
    }

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() 
{
  // Painting commands here which are opengl commands using GLEW.
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);  // Render in default framebuffer
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     RenderCube();  

   
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IN the Main function

QApplication application(argc, argv);

QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 2);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

return application.exec();
```

Comment: The default framebuffer is always the size of the window.

Comment: @NicolBolas  In this case it would be the size of Qwidget which is being promoted to the opegl class ?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the problem but... the underlying frame buffer size will generally be the same as for the `QWidget` itself and will adjust accordingly as the widget is resized.  If you want the widget to be a particular size then try calling [`QWidget::setFixedSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the size using `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`

> The QOpenGLFramebufferObject class encapsulates an OpenGL framebuffer
> object

The constructor accepts width and height. There are other overloaded constructors.
Look for documentation here.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#QOpenGLFramebufferObject-5

Call `bool QOpenGLFramebufferObject::bind()` to switch from system provided default framebuffer. Call `bool QOpenGLFramebufferObject::release()` to get back to the default framebuffer.

example:

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
QOpenGLFramebufferObject* frameBufferObject = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(1920, 1080, format);
frameBufferObject->bind();
```